# Webform one-time submission token+URL

Tags: webforms

I have two webforms:

1. Email webform: asks for the user's email address.
2. Voting webform: contains an entity selection list from which the user can select one and submit their vote.

In the email webform, there is a confirmation email sent to the submitted email address. In this confirmation email, I want to have an URL that points to the voting webform, and I want this to be a one-time-URL, as I want the users to access the voting webform in this way to validate that the submitted email is live and functioning.

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Webform has numerous capabilities for limiting submissions, and doesn't require arbitrary links: https://www.drupal.org/node/3080869